# AppEngine Datastore query with inequality and sort (different attribute). Workaround?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Hey guys I know this is an old issue but I am wondering if there any news about it:
I have a simple query where I want to do:

filter('created >=', somedatetime).order('-counter')

I tried: filter('created >=', somedatetime).order('-created').order('-counter') but because created is a datetime the results are pretty bad.

A user can go through a list with infinite scrolling and we can choose a time window of 7,30,90 days but it seems I cannot this very simple query.

I was thinking of break created to two attributes (dayofyear, year) so that I could use the IN operator but this could be hard as I have about 2M entries.

Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of (dayofyear, year) better use DateField. If this query is not done often you could sort with python's sort. If sorting with python is too expensive you will need to create DateField and query with `IN`. But new field will cost you some money too because it will result in many write ops.

Comment: I will go with Python. IN would be nice but in some cases I ll need 90 queries!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no way around this. This limitation exists due to how indexes are constructed. You'll simply have to do either the sorting or the filtering in memory, just as other databases would.